# Функция принимает век в римском формате и возращает в числовом

Tags: javascript

задача -  принимать в функции век в римском формате и выводить в числовом
Как сделал я- по сути функция не работает по непонятным причинам

```js
function getCentury(str) {
  str.split('')
  let counter=0
  for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    let I, II, III, V, X
    I=1
    II=2
    III=3
    V=5
    X=10
    counter=counter+str[i]
    if (str[0]===1)  counter-=1
  }
  console.log(counter)
}
getCentury('XXI')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заметил, что можно ходить по строке справа налево. Если численное значение текущего символа меньше, чем предыдущего - вычесть его из суммы (`IV: I < V → 5 - 1`), если больше либо равен, суммировать:

```
XVII:       // sum = I (1)
  I == I    // sum += 1
  V > I     // sum += 5
  X > V     // sum += 10
            // 17
```

```js
let test = [
  "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X",
  "XI", "XII", "XIII", "XIV", "XV", "XVI", "XVII", "XVIII", "XIX", "XX",
  "XXI", "XXII", "XXV", "XXX", "LXIV", "CCCLXIV", "CDLVI", "MMDI"
];

test.forEach( e => console.log(e + " → " + parseRoman(e)) );

/***/
function parseRoman(str) {
  let roman = {
    I: 1,
    V: 5,
    X: 10,
    L: 50,
    C: 100,
    D: 500,
    M: 1000
  };
  
  let sum = 0, last = 0;
  for( let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    let curr = roman[ str[i] ]; // Конвертирует римский символ в число
    
    sum += (curr >= last) ? curr : -curr;
    last = curr;
  }
  
  return sum;
}
```

Проверять на валидность - отдельная история, нужно больше думать)

Comment: А если соблюдать "правила" то вообще трындец))

Comment: а где я "тупил" ?

Comment: @babakov.roman678 `if (str[0]===1)  counter-=1` — str[0] — это всегда первая буква строки, в вашем случае, строка `"X"` на каждом круге идет проверка `"X" === 1` и она всегда дает false. Ну как минмум надо проверять `if ( str[i] == "I" )`, и где-то хранить предыдущий символ, чтобы как-то сравнить его с текущим.

Comment: ок, а что ещё??

Comment: @babakov.roman678 `let I, II, III, V, X` никак не использованы в коде. `counter = counter + str[i]` — здесь написано `0 + "X"` → `"0X"` т.е. str[i], оно же, "X" нигде не превращается в число 10. Для этого превращения и ввел в ответ объект `roman` вне цикла.